# Import provisioning profile to other mac from apple site

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, provisioning

I have a mac with contain my apple provisioning profile, this mac is "died", now i want to work with other mac, how can import my old provisioning profile ( with the apple certification ) ? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.**Revoke and create new certificate from your new Mac machine**,  update the provisioning profile ,download both and install all seems to work as expected.

**Note**: If you plan to do development and testing on ***multiple systems***, you will need to import your private key onto all of the systems you’ll be doing work on.

1. To export your private key and certificate for safe-keeping and for
   enabling development on multiple systems, open up the Keychain
   Access Application and select the ‘Keys’ category.
2. Control-Click on the private key associated with your iPhone
   Development Certificate and click ‘Export Items’ in the menu. The
   private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: public
   certificate that is paired with it.
3. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file
   format.
4. You will be prompted to create a password which is used when you
   attempt to import this key on another computer.
5. You can now transfer this .p12 file between systems. Double-click on the .p12 to install it on a system. You will be prompted for the
   password you entered in Step 4
6. Download and install new provisioning profile

Comment: thank you, just to be sure, after revoking the certificate, can i update my apps on the appStore ?

Comment: can somebody edit this code so the list looks like a list and not code, which it isn't. Horizontally scrolling to read these instructions is bad.

Comment: This can be done from Xcode now. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW18