# Valid signing identity not found - works on one machine, not the other

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I realise this is a common problem that people bump into, but I'd trawled all the answers I can find but have seen nothing better than "wipe everything, start again".

I'm hoping to do a little better than that. The problem is, I can only ever get my iOS provisioning to work on a single machine. I set it up on my Macbook Air and it stops working on my iMac. So I follow the 'wipe it all' including revocation of certificates and start from scratch on my iMac and it works, but breaks my Air.

There must be some fundamental piece of the jigsaw I'm missing.

I have downloaded and installed WWDR certificate.
I have downloaded and installed my developer certificate.
I have downloaded and installed my distribution certificate.

Everything should line up. I have all of my profiles in place, but they say "Valid signing identity not found".

What certificate is missing? What represents the signing identity? What is it that exists on one machine that doesn't on the other?

I'd really like to understand this and solve it properly.

Comment: please check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153227/import-provisioning-profile-to-other-mac-from-apple-site/13153501#13153501

Comment: The" Note" section of my answer will help you..

Answer (score 1):

I am not that clear on this concept too but i think the problem is that you dont have the proper certificates in your keychain access.

If you open up your keychain then you will find the private key certificate in one of the keychains on the left panel.

You will have to export the private key to get a `.p12` file that you can open in other machines and download the `.mobileprovision` from the developer website to make it work on different machines.

Shout if anything is not clear to you.

Comment: @ConfusedNoob can you come again