# Private key is not along with my developer certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I had the issue "Valid signing identity not found" when i download Provisioning profile from provisioning portal.

I tried couple of times to create the certificate from the fresh, but still facing the same "Valid signing identity not found" issue.

Looks like "Private key is not along with my developer certificate" when i see in the key chain. How could i solve this?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153227/import-provisioning-profile-to-other-mac-from-apple-site/13153501#13153501

Comment: I tried by revoking and creating the developer certificate. Still i don't find the Private key along with Developer Certificate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989368/add-private-key-to-certificate-or-vice-versa   check in the Link may be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worked, if i tried with another mac book. I am not sure, this one is mac book environment issue.

Steps followed
1. Revoked my current certificate from provisioning portal
2. Created new CSR from new Mac Book
3. Created Developer Certificate by submitting the new CSR.

This developer certificate works successful new Mac.

I tried the same certificate by exporting from new mac to my old mac. It's also successful.